# [MSYS2][Windows 7][shared library port from Linux] Is there a ldconfig equivalent in MSYS2?

Tags: linux, gnu, shared, msys2

I use a personnal library for educationnal purposes called "uepwide".
It contains lotta functions to enjoy the console (terminal) environnement in Linux.
As I use what is expected to be "portable" called POSIX and UTF8 GNU functions (wchar.h related),  I tried to port it into Windows environnement thru MSYS2 environnement (Cygwin doesn't work).

I use the makefile from Linux and tried a different version for Windows... as it is 19 years now I didn't touch a Windows environment for programming purposes, I have forgotten all was about dll are working on Windows. I just hope it is not necessary to include things like __declspec(dllimport), etc... in every test source code used on Linux to check if everything is good with the shared library turned into dll.

Here is the makefile (the windows part) I used:

```
dllwin:     uep_wide.c uep_wide.h setElementEx.c getElementEx.c
        @echo "Librairie partagée compilée..."
        @echo "...installation au niveau du système d'exploitation !!"
        gcc -c -fPIC -O3 uep_wide.c -o libuepwide.o
        @echo "...compilation des add-ons..."
        gcc -c -fPIC -O3 setElementEx.c -o setElementEx.o
        gcc -c -fPIC -O3 getElementEx.c -o getElementEx.o
        gcc -c -fPIC -O3 getPIDByName.c -o getPIDByName.o
        @echo "...compilation de la librairie..."
        gcc -shared -Wall libuepwide.o setElementEx.o getElementEx.o getPIDByName.o -lpthread -lm -o uepwide.dll 
        @cp uepwide.dll /usr/lib
        @echo "TERMINE"
```

As there is no lib64 folder in MSYS2 (why ?) I put it in /usr/lib.
When I compile my test code source trying to use this dll...

```
CFLAGS=`pkg-config uepwide linkedlist --cflags`
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config uepwide linkedlist --libs`

test1: test1.c
test2: test2.c
test3: test3.c
test4: test4.c
...
```

I got this error from the linker...

```
cc `pkg-config uepwide --cflags`  `pkg-config uepwide --libs`  test1.c   -o test1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -luepwide
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test1] Error 1
```

It shows that pkg-config is working but that uepwide is unknown by MSYS2/Windows because this dll hasn't been "registered" as ldconfig does in Linux.

How do I "register" this dll ?

[EDIT 1]
This is the uepwide.pc file:

```
libdir=/usr/lib
includedir=/librairies/uep_wide
Libs: -L${libdir} -luepwide -lpthread -lm
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

[EDIT 2]
As MSYS2 seems to be a three in one environment (see comments) I looked the folder structure and saw that there is six locations where pkgconfig is localed...

- ***c:\msys64\usr\lib***
- ***c:\msys64\usr\share***
- c:\msys64\mingw32\lib
- c:\msys64\mingw32\share
- c:\msys64\mingw64\lib
- c:\msys64\mingw64\share

Those related to the choosen environment MSYS2 MSYS are in italic and bold. So I put the dll in **/usr/lib** as **c:\msys64** is *chrooted*.

[EDIT 3]
As I don't want to change anything in the source code for every test application I will follow the clue indicating that in Windows -- I forgotten -- the dll are first searched in folder then in PATH.
So as I don't want to change #include <uep_wide.h> to #include "uep_wide.h" (that is why I use pkg-config) I will check if the PATH is correct.

[EDIT 4]
Very busy, sorry for the lateness...
It works using the dll in **/usr/bin** instead of **/usr/lib**.
In the other hand, Windows seems to have issues echoing the utf8 characters. Need to debug what is wrong.

Comment: *"I put the dll in /usr/lib"* Dlls belong in `bin`, not, `lib`. On MinGW, at least before a certain version, it wasn't possible to link directly to a dll. Instead, writing `-lfoo`, among other things, tries linking against a stub `libfoo.dll.a`, which then loads the dll at runtime. I wouldn't rely on linking directly against a dll, and use this method instead. (So, only `libuepwide.dll.a` needs to be in the (compile-time) linker search path, not the dll.

Comment: *"don't want to change #include <uep_wide.h> to #include "uep_wide.h" ... I will check if the PATH is correct"* My comment about PATH pertains only to *runtime* dll search. Compile-time search done by the linker (and header search) should be unaffected. You're only supposed to keep the `bin` directory in PATH, not `lib` nor `include`.

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively using Cygwin right now.

MSYS2 has three modes. The current mode is indicated by the magenta text in the terminal: `MSYS`, `MINGW32`, or `MINGW64`. The modes differ in environment variables, most notably `PATH`.

The modes have three corresponding sets of packages, including compilers and libraries. The package names start with prefixes, indicating their modes.

- `MINGW32` packages are prefixed with `mingw-w64-i686-`. They're used to compile for 32-bit Windows.
- `MINGW64` packages are prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-`. They're used to compiler for 64-bit windows.
- `MSYS` packages are unprefixed, they're used to compile for what is essentially a MSYS2's own fork of Cygwin.

All binaries in each group of packages are build by the corresponding compilers.

You almost never want to use the `MSYS` mode. (If you want Cygwin, you might as well use Cygwin itself).

Maybe you can make it work under `MSYS` mode, but I suggest switching to `MINGW64`. Enable it by starting the shell using `mingw64.exe`.

If you use `MINGW64`, you have to prefer packages prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-` to unprefixed packages: you use prefixed packages for all compilers and libraries, and unprefixed packages only for utilities that have nothing to do with building, such as `bash`, `make`, `grep` - which have no prefixed alternatives (well, Make does, but it's jank).

Files pertaining to `MINGW32` and `MINGW64` reside in `/mingw32` and `/mingw64`. Files pertaining to `MSYS` reside in `/`.

So you need to use `/mingw64/lib` instead of `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Thank you. When compiling with MINGW64, the termios.h is not found. The only "environment" that let me compile my library is MSYS.

Comment: `hurukan@VirtualWin7 MINGW64 /usr/include
# ls -lah termios.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 hurukan None 92 Mar 17 09:17 termios.h` this is what I found.

Comment: `uep_wide.c:24:10: fatal error: termios.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <termios.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:29: dllwin] Error 1
` that is what I have...

Comment: under MSYS it compiles without any errors.

Comment: ...but I can't link the dll with nothing... ldconfig equivalent is missing...

Comment: @HurukanImperialStepper On Windows, the runtime dll search path is always "directory of the .exe, then some system directories, then PATH". But the linker (at build time) might not search those, it searches the directories you give it with `-L…`. I suggest installing some random library from the package manager, and looking which files are placed where, and what's in `.pc` file.